# HandlerMethodArgumentResolver supportsParameter Map<String,String>

Tags: java, spring

I have this class to handle a Map argument:

```
@Configuration
public class MapHandlerMethodArgumentResolver
    implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver
{
    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter( MethodParameter parameter )
    {
        return parameter.getParameterType().isAssignableFrom( Map.class );
    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveArgument( MethodParameter parameter, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest, WebDataBinderFactory binderFactory )
    {
        return Map.of();
    }
}
```

On the method `supportsParameter` I want to check as well that the Map is of type `Map<String, String>`.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hopes this helps:

```
@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
    ParameterizedType genericParameterType = (ParameterizedType) parameter.getGenericParameterType();
    return parameter.getParameterType().isAssignableFrom(Map.class)
            && genericParameterType.getActualTypeArguments()[0].getClass().isAssignableFrom(String.class)
            && genericParameterType.getActualTypeArguments()[1].getClass().isAssignableFrom(String.class);

}
```